# How to set the option pp.decimal in Z3 Java API?

Tags: java, z3

I need to set the option ":pp.decimal" to "true" in my solver object.

```
(set-option :pp.decimal true)
```

What I use is the JAVA API. The Z3 solver is version 4.3.2.0. So how can I handle this in my program code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem by setting the option to the static class "Global":

```
Global.setParameter("pp.decimal", "true");
```

Comment: Yes, that's should work. The Solver class also has a function called setParameters if you need different options for different Solvers.